Is There A Way To Test Dead Phone's CPU, RAM, SoC?
I have a dead phone that can have its flash memory accessed via BROM MtkClient, it can be read and written to, but the phone doesn't turn on. Rebooted one time and it didn't turn back on. Seems to be a problem with a charging circuit/board that could be replaced.
Is there a way to run some tests on the mainboard via something like MtkClient or some other method using BROM to find out if CPU, RAM, etc. are OK?
Thanks.

Welcome MarkSpace! I've been assigned your question in the review queues. On initial inspection, it appears to be non-specific to Android, which would make it off-topic.  But I can also potentially see ways it could be Android-specific (thus on-topic).  If you can edit your question to indicate how it is an Android-specific question, it will prevent your question from being closed.  Or, if you think it is not Android-specific, just let us know, and it can be closed.  Whatever you decide is an accurate representation is fine.  Again, welcome!

BTW, I'm actually interested in learning answers to your good question too, but our community has guidelines, and that's a guideline that is unlikely to change (on the other hand, every community member is always welcome to suggest guidelines be changed, but I think most community members and moderators will be in favour of keeping that guideline).

I think you are right, actually. It's halfway to Android, but not quite there, might post it to Electronics. Let's close it, thanks.

Will do.  I didn't flag it during the review because I thought it unfair until you had a chance to respond and I felt the question could be in a gray area.  I'll flag it now, and then if 2 others (or 1 moderator) agree, it will get closed.  I don't recall if that you, as the OP, will be able to comment here once it is closed, but before it is closed (or even afterwards, if it is possible), please do link to wherever you choose to ask your question.  I think it's an interesting and useful question.

Posted to Electronics.SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/723067/57290
